# Is it possible to connect a project to different BDs, as you'd connect it to different APIs?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, connection

As a college student I did some deployment diagrams of a Spring Boot project I'm making, and in them I stated that I would fetch stock data from 3 sources: web **scraping**, API connection and DB connection. Deploy diagram:

[image: Deploy diagram]

As development team we've already done web **scraper** and API connector components (they are not 'artifacts', diagram's wrong there), but when it comes to DB connection I can't seem to find any source to connect to. Every web page that offer connection to a DB are eventually, API connections.

Is it even possible to connect to a DB the way I modeled it?

Any orientation appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of security issue, you will not find `any` web site that provide you a way to connect directly to their `database`. The only way to access the `database` is throught an API (provided by the web site) or `hack` the web site (what I would not recommand).

Also to answer you question as mentionned in the title : `Yes! You can connect to any number of databases, but it depends if you are allowed to do it`.

Comment: I was thinking something like it and I feel like this is the right answer. So, I'm sorry if I sound naive but I'm new to development world: you say I won't find any 'DB service' that will grant me access through credentials to some database? I mean mainly free services like mentioned, I won't afford any kind of paid service as it is university-related work.

Comment: You can have access to your own `database` if you have an account with a cloud provider such as `MS Azure` or `AWS`. Most of the time these services are free if you use it under a certain amount of resources.